# SSLSockets between Swift iOS app and Java program

Tags: java, swift, sockets, ssl

I am trying to create an iOS app that needs to communicate with a Java program via SSLSockets. I already have a Java client and an Android app that work with the Java server, and now I need the iOS app, but I am really new to Swift.

I managed to exchange messages on a plain socket between a Swift app and a Java program, but now I want to migrate to SSL Sockets and I am stuck.

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Starscream` as your websocket framework: https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream

This also supports `SSL Pinning` to provide even greater security:
https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream#ssl-pinning

Comment: Actually I don't want to use websockets but classic TCP sockets. For now I create the socket with CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost, but it's a plain socket, not an SSLSocket.

Comment: I found a link that may be of use: [link](http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=950). This is Objective-C code, but translating it into Swift should be doable. Gonna try this.